# How to locate text with bounding box, and put the locate text on white background

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to locate text using bounding boxes, in next step I want to put only the located text on white background, and for this I want to use the code given in this url.  [Get white text on black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745730/get-white-text-on-black-background/77259192?noredirect=1#comment136202886_77259192)
how to modify it to locate text and put bounding boxes around it?

[image] in this example its plain background.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2LeK.jpg) another image where text need to be located and to be put on white background.

I am able to locate the text I want to put only text on white background using Python. the located text are segments to be put on white background.

Comment: Forgive me, I keep managing to get confused by your question.  If you saying that you have identified the bounding boxes and you want to convert them to black text on a white background, then the grayscale and thresholding steps in the referenced question's steps will get you black-on-white and white-on-black text.  And examples where the background is uniform like this it should be easy to identify the white-on-black regions by just looking at the color of most of the boundary.  Then you invert those regions to get black-on-white.

Comment: If on the other hand you are asking how to identify the bounding boxes that, in general, is the harder problem and why text identification in the midst of other confounding information forms the basis for many "are you a human" challenges.

Comment: In any case, you might want to investigate the pyteseract package.  https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract

Comment: Can you be sure that each bounding box contains only the two colors?  I.e. the text color and the background color?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there are only two colors in each bounding box, convert the region to grayscale, threshold on a value between the two values. If the predominant color in the image is black, then invert the image.

Since two distinct colors can map to the same grayscale, a color threshold in place of the grayscale-then-threshold is probably safer, but it would be slightly harder to define the threshold to use.